# new word in interfaces in c#

Tags: c#, interface

```
using System;

namespace random

{

    interface IHelper
    {
        void HelpMeNow();
    }
    public class Base : IHelper
    {
        public void HelpMeNow()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Base.HelpMeNow()");
        }
    }
    public class Derived : Base
    {
        public new void HelpMeNow()            ///this line
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Derived.HelpMeNow()");
        }
    }
    class Test
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Derived der = new Derived();
            der.HelpMeNow();
            IHelper helper = (IHelper)der;
            helper.HelpMeNow();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

the new keyword in the commented line is a little confusing for me. It jsut mean it overrides the implementation of method in base class. 
Why not use override keyword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really overriding it, it's **shadowing** it.  Given a reference to a `Derived` object, `Base`'s `HelpMeNow` function will not be accessible<sup>1</sup>, and `derivedObject.HelpMeNow()` will call `Derived`'s implementation.

This is not the same as overriding a virtual function, which `HelpMeNow` is not.  If a `Derived` object is stored in a reference to a `Base`, or to an `IHelper`, then `Base`'s `HelpMeNow()` will be called, and `Derived`'s implementation will be inaccessible.

```
Derived derivedReference = new Derived();
Base    baseReference    = derivedReference;
IHelper helperReference  = derivedReference;

derivedReference.HelpMeNow(); // outputs "Derived.HelpMeNow()"
baseReference.HelpMeNow();    // outputs "Base.HelpMeNow()"
helperReference.HelpMeNow();  // outputs "Base.HelpMeNow()"
```

Of course, if the above is not the desired behavior, and it's usually not, there are two possibilities.  If you control `Base`, simply change `HelpMeNow()` to virtual, and override it in `Derived` instead of shadowing it.  If you don't control `Base`, then you can at least fix it halfway, by reimplementing `IHelper`, like so:

```
class Derived : Base, IHelper{
    public new void HelpMeNow(){Console.WriteLine("Derived.HelpMeNow()");}

    void IHelper.HelpMeNow(){HelpMeNow();}
}
```

This version of `Derived` uses what's called **explicit interface implementation**, which allows you to satisfy the contract of implementing an interface without adding the implementation to your class's public interface.  In this example, we already have an implementation in `Derived`'s public interface that's inherited from `Base`, so we have to explicitly implement `IHelper` to change it<sup>2</sup>.  In this example, we just forward the implementation of `IHelper.HelpMeNow` to our public interface, which is the shadow of `Base`'s.

So with this change, a call to `baseReference.HelpMeNow()` still outputs "Base.HelpMeNow()", but a call to `helperReference.HelpMeNow()` will now output "Derived.HelpMeNow()".  Not as good as changing `Base`'s implementation to virtual, but as good as we're gonna get if we don't control `Base`.

<sup>1</sup><sup><sub>Exception: it *is* accessible from within methods of `Derived`, but only when qualified with `base.`, as in `base.HelpMeNow()`.</sub></sup>
<sup>2</sup><sup><sub>Notice that we also have to declare `IHelper` as an interface the class implements, even though we inherit this declaration from `Base`.</sub></sup>

Comment: Wow, what a reply. thank you so much. Explained it better than anything I could ever imagine

Answer (score 0):

In general, if interface IBase implements a member DoSomething, and IDerived inherits/implements Ibase, it expected that IDerived.DoSomething will be synonymous with IBase.DoSomething.  In general, this is useful since it saves implementers of the class from having to provide redundant implementations.  There are, however, some cases where a derived interface must implement a member which has the same name as a member in the base interface, but which will have to be implemented separately.  The most common such situations are (1) the derived method will have a different return type from the base type, or (2) the base interface(s) implements a ReadOnly and/or WriteOnly property(s) with a certain and the derived type should implement a Read-Write property.  For whatever reason, if interface IReadableFoo provides a read-only property Foo, IWritableFoo provides a write-only property Foo, and interface IMutableFoo simply inherits both, the compiler won't know whether a reference to Foo refers to IReadableFoo.Foo or IWritableFoo.Foo.  Even though only IReadableFoo.Foo can be read, and only IWritableFoo.Foo can be written, neither vb.net nor C# can resolve the overload unless one implements a new read-write property Foo which handles both.